# JavaScript Search Date with Select tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a search that will find a certain date by month and year by using select tags, if the txt includes the value of month and the value of year in the string, then I want an alert to appear, but I get the error `txt.indexOf is not a function`

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
today = new Date();

txt.innerHTML = ('' + today.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes());

var month = document.getElementById('month');
var year = document.getElementById('year');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (txt.indexOf(month.value) & txt.indexOf(year.value)) {
    alert('yay');
    console.log('yay');
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="txt"></p>

<select id="month">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
</select>

<select id="year">
  <option>2016</option>
  <option>2017</option>
  <option>2018</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">
  search
</button>
```

Comment: Did you mean `txt.innerHTML.indexOf` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `indexOf` method on the **DOM node**. Which does not have that method.

`indexOf` is method which can be called on [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)...

Here is your code modified to work properly (am not in love with the implementation, but can not commit now to make it proper).

- please don't use `alert()` in 2017
- switch to const / let instead of var
- rethink your code structure

```js
var txtElement = document.getElementById('txt');
today = new Date();

var dateString = '' + today.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes();
txtElement.innerHTML = dateString;
txtElement.setAttribute('data-month', today.getMonth() + 1);
txtElement.setAttribute('data-year', today.getFullYear());

var month = document.getElementById('month');
var year = document.getElementById('year');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var currentMonth = txtElement.getAttribute('data-month');
  var currentYear = txtElement.getAttribute('data-year');
  if (currentMonth === month.value && currentYear === year.value) {
    alert('yay');
    console.log('yay');
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="txt"></p>

<select id="month">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
</select>

<select id="year">
  <option>2016</option>
  <option>2017</option>
  <option>2018</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">
  search
</button>
```

Comment: there are no errors but it does not display the alert or log.

Comment: I edited my answer to be less error prone. Now it uses the data attributes to match the month / year. It works if the month and year from select boxes match the one in the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) class *doesn't* have `indexOf` on it, nor does [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) return an Array. What I would recommend is that you instead write it using the `innerHTML` property from the `txt` variable or something.

Note: I use [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-env) and [`eslint-config-airbnb`](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb), so your style may differ.

```
const txt = document.getElementById('txt');
const today = new Date();

txt.innerHTML = `${today.toLocaleDateString()} ${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}`;

const month = document.getElementById('month');
const year = document.getElementById('year');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const value = txt.innerHTML;
  if (value.includes(month.value) && value.includes(year.value)) {
    alert('yay'); // eslint-disable-line no-alert
    console.log('yay'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  }
});
```